# Git ls-files behaviour

Tags: git, wildcard, git-ls-files

It's not clear how `git ls-files` using *wildcards* actually functions.

I started with the `git ls-files *.*` command which works okay. It shows all the files under version control in all the underlying subdirectories
But now I want to select a set of files. Example : `"Device_*.xml"`

So I execute `git ls-files Device_*.xml` but this gives no result?!

I am aware the command is case sensitive. What is wrong? Below is the list of command's I execute with the output. Git version used : 2.6.1.windows.1

```
D:\GIT\repo>git clean -xdf
D:\GIT\repo>git reset --hard
```

`HEAD` is now at `7de8f5b` [IP-826-generic-configuration-management-ticket] Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into IP-826-generic-configuration-management-ticket

```
D:\GIT\repo>git status
```

On branch IP-826-generic-configuration-management-ticket

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/IP-826-generic-configuration-management-ticket'.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

```
 D:\GIT\repo\Imagepipe\SettingsDB\GeneratedDevicesAllPlatforms>dir Device_*.xml /s

<LOT OF DEVICE_*.xml FILES HERE> 

12/10/2015  10:46               681 Device_GeneratedDevices_0-0-0_0.xml
1 File(s)            681 bytes

 Directory of            D:\GIT\repo\Tools\DevTools\SettingsGenerator\SLIB2_GenerateSettings\Test\DB7\GeneratedDevices\D1
12/10/2015  10:46             1,997 Device_D1_0-0-0_0.xml
1 File(s)          1,997 bytes

 Directory of     D:\GIT\repo\Tools\DevTools\SettingsGenerator\SLIB2_GenerateSettings\Test\DB7\S_NOCHECK

12/10/2015  10:46             1,558 Device_S_NOCHECK_0-0-0_0.xml
1 File(s)          1,558 bytes

 Directory of     D:\GIT\repo\Tools\DevTools\SettingsGenerator\SLIB2_GenerateSettings\Test\DB7\S_TEST

12/10/2015  10:46             1,536 Device_S_TEST_0-0-0_0.xml
1 File(s)          1,536 bytes

Total Files Listed:
         968 File(s)     14,032,982 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  18,400,256,000 bytes free

D:\GIT\repo>git ls-files Device_*.xml
D:\GIT\repo>

**No result!**
```

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/git/git/commit/de8bada2bf63d274b8f7759f0ffd0b7669e52eca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that if you use the asterisk (`*`) in a **non-string** environment, the command line interpreter will perform *expansion* itself: it will look to files in the *directory*, not necessary under version control and add these as argument. For example, say the directory contains a files:

```
foo-a.txt
foo-b.txt
```

and you call `git ls-files foo-*.txt`, actually you call the command `git ls-files foo-a.txt foo-b.txt`. Now it is possible that`foo-c.txt` is under version control, but was once removed, and that `foo-a.txt` and `foo-b.txt` are not, resulting in the fact hat no file is listed.

If you however use the asterisk **in a string environment**, like `git ls-files "foo-*.txt"`, **the asterisk is interpreted by `git`**. So in case there is a file in the repository that matches the wildcard, it will be returned.

**Example**:

```
> git init 
Initialized empty Git repository in /foo/bar/.git/
> ls
> touch foo-c.txt 
> git add .; git commit -am 'foo-c'
[master (root-commit) 3523fc3] foo-c
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 foo-c.txt
> rm foo-c.txt 
> git ls-files
foo-c.txt
> git ls-files foo-*.txt
fish: No matches for wildcard 'foo-*.txt'.
git ls-files foo-*.txt
             ^
> git ls-files 'foo-*.txt'
foo-c.txt
> touch foo-a.txt
> touch foo-b.txt
> git ls-files 'foo-*.txt'
foo-c.txt
> git ls-files foo-*.txt
```

In the example, we first setup a git repository, then we create a file `foo-c.txt`. Now we add that file and make a commit. Next we remove the file. If we now call `git ls-files foo-*.txt`, it is `fish` (the shell) that complains that no such file can be found. If we however pass `foo-*.txt` in a string, `git` has no problem matching `foo-c.txt`.

If we later add `foo-a.txt` and `foo-b.txt` to the directory, by performing the wildcard outside the string environment, `git` gets `git ls-files foo-a.txt foo-b.txt`, but since no such file is under subversioning, it returns nothing (it cannot find these files). If you however use a wildcard withing a string, again it will come up with `foo-c.txt`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this under windows but the first "git ls-files foo-*.txt" command still returns foo-c.txt

Comment: @MarkdeBont: it should return `foo-c.txt`, since it is the only file under version control. See the example.